# API for Java and JavaScript app integration

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, sql-server, java

Are there any APIs to make calls or integrate JavaScript functions to a Java written application?  I have come across Rhino's liveconnect.js, but this is uncharted territory for me, and would like a bit more information.  My scenario is using a Java application parallel to a JavaScript application wherein the data that is recorded from the Java app is made available in the JavaScript application as well.  This is all CRM/SOA stuff.

The customer would enter a request in the java application, but the same request is passed to the JavaScript app.

I am using an Esri ArcGIS JS API Web Application with ArcGIS Server and SQL Server 2008.

Node.js could be used, however now, think of it this way; 
The ArcGIS JS API web application is the orgin of all spatial components for a call center application which is public facing and internal, there's a Java application that is running parallel to it, we would like to pass any requests originated in the Java application the JavaScript application's database.

Comment: Assuming you are running javascript only on client (i.e. no node.js stuff) and Java on the server, then I am not even clear how you can share data between them. I would say you need to have a restful server to pass on the information to the javascript piece. Can you elaborate a bit on the setup? Is the data source the database?

Comment: This seems to be a cross-post of http://stackoverflow.com/q/27929043